# Properties of a class instance not updating in test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm adding tests to legacy code and am running into an issue when testing an instance method that updates some of the instance's properties. The test fails because it appears that the values are not updating. However, if I console.log out the value of all of the properties at the end of the update() function it looks like they are all being updated correctly.  Is there a way to refresh the instance of the class in the test to get the new values?

Here is a simplified version of the class:

```
class Party {
  public ticketIds: string[];
  public isCheckedIn: boolean;
  public currentZoneId: number | undefined; 

  constructor(ticketIds) {
    this.ticketIds = ticketIds;
    this.isCheckedIn = false;
  }

  public update() {
    const orderInformation = OrderService.getInformation(this.ticketIds[0])

    // Update the party information based on what is returned from OrderService
    this.isCheckedIn = orderInformation.checkedIn;
    this.currentZoneId = orderInformation.currentZone.id;
  }
}
```

And here is my test:

```
it("update() should update the party information", () => {
  OrderService.getInformation.mockReturnValue({ checkedIn: true, currentZone: { id: 1} })
  const party = new Party(["ticket-1", "ticket-2"])

  // Check that the party was initialized with the expected values
  expect(party.ticketIds).toBe(["ticket-1", "ticket-2"])
  expect(party.isCheckedIn).toBe(false)
  expect(party.currentZoneId).toBe(undefined)

  // Update party and check values again
  party.update()
  expect(party.ticketIds).toBe(["ticket-1", "ticket-2"])
  expect(party.isCheckedIn).toBe(true)
  expect(party.currentZoneId).toBe(1)
})
```

Comment: This should work - are you sure you're getting the mocked values from `OrderService.getInformation()`?

Comment: @pishpish I just double checked and everything seems to be mocked correctly. I even threw in a console.log at the end of the `update()` function and that shows all of the correct values. It just seems like the variable inside the test isn't updating.